# How to Filter Products by category and its attributes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on E-commerce Website in Larvel.

I've added products to Database now I'm trying to filter them on the basis of color, price, size, brand, etc. attributes

**My Blade file**

```html
 <form action="{{ route('shop') }}" method="GET" id="filter-form">
 
 // input fields coming from the shop function
 
<input type="submit" value="Filter" class="btn  btn-sm btn-primary">
<button type="submit" name="clear" value="1" class="btn btn-sm  btn-danger">Clear
Filters</button>

</form>
```

**My Product Model (using scope)**

```html
class Product extends Model
{
use HasFactory;

public function gallery()
{
return $this->hasMany(Gallery::class, 'product_id');
}
public function category()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
public function subcategory()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Subcategory::class, 'subcategory_id');
}
public function childCategory()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Childcategory::class, 'childcategory_id');
}
public function brands()
{
return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class, 'brand_id');
}
public function attributes()
{
return $this->hasMany(Pro_attributes::class, 'product_id');
}



// Scope to filter products by category slug
public function scopeByCategory($query, $categorySlug)
{
return $query->whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($categorySlug) {
$query->where('slug', $categorySlug);
});
}
// Scope to filter products by subcategory slug
public function scopeBySubcategory($query, $subcategorySlug)
{
return $query->whereHas('subcategory', function ($query) use ($subcategorySlug) {
$query->where('slug', $subcategorySlug);
});
}
// Scope to filter products by child category slug
public function scopeByChildCategory($query, $slug)
{
return $query->whereHas('childCategory', function ($query) use ($slug) {
$query->where('slug', $slug);
});
}
}
```

**incoming Data with dd($request->all()); in function**

```html
array:5 [▼ // app\Http\Controllers\Frontend\ShopController.php:55
  "minamount" => "$25"
  "maxamount" => "$870"
  "color" => "7"
  "size" => "8"
  "brand" => "1"
]
```

And Last

**My Shop Function**

```html
public function shop(Request $request, $categorySlug = null, $subcategorySlug = null, $slug = null)
{
// dd($request->all());
$data['Home_slider'] = Homeslider::where('status', '1')->get();
$data['category'] = Category::where('status', '1')->get();
$data['user'] = Auth::user();

// Retrieve the products based on the incoming category, subcategory, or child category
$products = Product::query();

if ($categorySlug) {
$products->byCategory($categorySlug);
}
if ($subcategorySlug) {
$products->bySubcategory($subcategorySlug);
}
if ($slug) {
$products->byChildCategory($slug);
}

$products->with('gallery');

// Sidebar Filters Data sending to the blade file
$data['min_price'] = $products->min('current_price');
$data['max_price'] = $products->max('current_price');
$data['color'] = Pro_attributes::where('name', 'color')->with('attribute_options')->get();
$data['size'] = Pro_attributes::where('name', 'size')->with('attribute_options')->get();
$data['brand'] = Brand::where('status', 1)->with('products')->get();


// Apply filters on the basis of incoming data from form 
if ($request->filled('minamount') && $request->filled('maxamount')) {
$minPrice = (int) str_replace('$', '', $request->input('minamount'));
$maxPrice = (int) str_replace('$', '', $request->input('maxamount'));
$products->whereBetween('current_price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice]);
}

if ($request->filled('color')) {
$color = (array) $request->input('color');
$products->whereHas('attributes.attribute_options', function ($query) use ($color) {
$query->whereIn('id', $color);
});
}

if ($request->filled('size')) {
$size = (array) $request->input('size');
$products->whereHas('attributes.attribute_options', function ($query) use ($size) {
$query->whereIn('id', $size);
});
}

if ($request->filled('brand')) {
$brand = (array) $request->input('brand');
$products->whereHas('brands', function ($query) use ($brand) {
$query->whereIn('id', $brand);
});
}

// Execute the query and get the products
$data['products'] = $products->paginate(12);
return view('frontend.shop', $data);
}
```

i've pasted all of my code for better understanding

now

**What i have done**

i have retrived products successfully on the basis of attributes (size, color etc.)

**What i want**

the products that i have retrived are not coming on the base of category, subcateory or child category

i mean i have added men fashion category but when i want to filter products with (attributes (size, color etc)) from men fashion category it is also showing me other category's products like women category

same issue for subcategory or child category

please find out my issue i want that filter should only apply on the products that already have been loaded within category, sub category, or child category slugs

no ajax requires simple laravel

please replay i'm waiting for your response

before applying filters

[image]

after applying filter

[image]

as you can see women category's products is coming after applying filters in mens-fashion

Comment: somebody reply please

Comment: can you add screenshot of view of categories , color and brand.. like click on category then that category product show

Comment: okay, wait please

Comment: yes i see your query is perfect... it gives you both male and female result... bcz how system know white color is for male or female?

Comment: if ($categorySlug) {
$products->byCategory($categorySlug);
}     you need to get  $categorySlug every time on the basis of color size and brand then it gives you your desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($request->filled('color')) {
        $color = (array) $request->input('color');
        $category_id = $request->category_id;  // every time filter you need this
        $products->whereHas('attributes.attribute_options', function ($query) use ($color) {
        $query->whereIn('id', $color);
        })
        ->where('category_id',$category_id)  // if your product table has category_id
        ->get();
        }
```